# change collation on all objects in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to change the collation on a restored database to match the server and the tempdb database. I understand that I can use ALTER DATABASE and ALTER TABLE to change collertion. But will it only affect new data added to the tables? Do i have to go down the road with

- Script needed to re-create your user databases and all the objects in them
- Export all your data using a tool such as the bcp Utility
- Create a new database
- Script the tables in right collection and import all data.

It's a Microsoft Sql Server 2008

Comment: Alter COLUMN will change the collation of existing data but you can't have indexes/constraints that reference the column.  I think the export/import method is the cleanest but you could create new objects in the same database, migrate data, drop the old tables, and rename.

Comment: @DanGuzman-SQLServerMVP: If the (old) tables are referenced by other tables, wouldn't you also need to drop the foreign keys (and recreate them afterwards)?

Comment: Yes, the same consideration applies to foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this script:

```
DECLARE @collation NVARCHAR(64)
SET @collation = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'

SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA  + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] '
  + 'ALTER COLUMN [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] '
  + DATA_TYPE + '(' + CASE CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
        WHEN -1 THEN 'MAX' 
        ELSE CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) END + ') '
  + 'COLLATE ' + @collation + ' '
  + CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' END
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE  COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL
AND TABLE_NAME IN ( SELECT TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'  )
AND COLLATION_NAME <> @collation
```

Also check [Set or Change the Database Collation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx)

Comment: Note that the ALTER COLUMN will fail if index, primary key constraints, or unique constraints reference the column.